# Java Startup Application [WINDOWS]

Tags: java, startup

i have this simple code in java that shutdown the pc. What can i add to run this at Windows StartUp?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Spegni {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = runtime.exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe");
        OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
        os.write("shutdown -s -f -t 0\n\r".getBytes());
        os.close();
        try {
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }  
}
```

Comment: do you want to shutdown on startup !!!!!?

Comment: yes i want this only to troll

Comment: hmmm this has to do with the setup program or you may create a task in windows, there are no other choices.

Answer (score 0):

start, run:

```
shell:startup
```

and then place the shortcut there. Happy trolling.